# kendo ui GRID Bound columns with if statement

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

iam using kendo ui for MVC and iam trying to build dynamic

table (each time others columns will show)

can u please tell me if its possible to populate grid columns only with certain conditions

something like this :

```
   columns.Bound(c => c.a).Title(ViewBag.SearchBy+" id").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "search_by_id" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.b);
if(1>0)
{
            columns.Bound(c => c.c).Title("Conversions");
            columns.Bound(c => c.d).Title("Conversion rate").Format("{0:p1}"); ;
}
```

thank u

Comment: what you trying to do here hide whole column or just the cell value..??

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use an if statement when creating columns:

```
if (someCondition)
{
   columns.Bound(c => c.c).Title("Conversions");
}
else
{
   columns.Bound(c => c.d).Title("Conversion rate").Format("{0:p1}");
}
```